# Paste text when option not offered by the app?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way to paste message if an app doesn't offer the paste option when you hold down in the text area?  (Specifically Clash of Clans.)  Alternate keyboard for storing text or something like that?  Or with iOS 8, a keyboard with a paste button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With new keyboards, one option to accomplish this turned out the be [Paste It!](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paste-it-keyboard/id917915202?mt=8)  It's a keyboard app that lets you type into the main app, and then find any one of a number of messages to paste later.  Nice!

I think there are other keyboards out there providing similar functionality, but this was the first free option I found.

Answer (score 1):

Use shortcuts --- settings/keyboard

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Clash of Clans? No, it uses its own non-standard text fields, so you can't do anything at all in them. In general though, a double tap in most apps will allow a paste even if they don't normally. This works in password fields that are blocked from pasting as well, usually.

Comment: Yeah, but there could be a work around.  the 6 plus has a paste button on the keyboard.  And some of the new keyboards will paste in the words it suggested just fine.  So theoretically the keyboard could paste in a whole sentence for me.  Maybe I will just have to write that keyboard myself....

Comment: You can't even move the insertion point in Clash of Clans to go back and fix typos. In my clans we have many typos enshrined. glod, for example.